# Determine whether a network (graph) is connected based on its matrix

Tags: matlab, graph, social-networking, octave

How can I determine from a given m x n matrix desribing a two-mode network whether it is connected or not?

Of course once can create a data structure for finding it out – but is there any mathematical solution?

I found out for n x n matrices (one-mode network) it is easy: The solution would be: `M * M` and then looking at the diagonal in the resulting matrix. If there is any zero on the diagonal then it is not connected. Isn't that true?

What would be your suggestion for both problems?

Answer (score 1):

It is not that simple for **one-mode networks**, but you're close.

The network matrix `M` itself tells you which node is connected to which other node in one step. `M * M` tells you which node is connected to which other node in *exactly two* steps, `M ^ 3` whether in *exactly three* steps, and so on. "Exactly" is important, because if nodes are not connected to themselves (zero diagonal elements), then `M * M` does not only obtain two-step connectivity, but also loses one-step connectivity.

The products (powers) are therefore more useful if all nodes are connected to themselves:

```
A = (M + eye(size(M)) > 0)
```

This step also converts a weighted matrix into a pure adjacency matrix. Now

```
(A ^ i > 0)
```

gives you the information whether two nodes are connected in `i` steps *or less*. In a network with `n = size(M, 1)` nodes, the distance between two nodes can be at most `n - 1` steps. Therefore

```
C = (A ^ (n - 1) > 0)
```

gives you the information whether two nodes are connected *at all*. The whole network is connected if there are no pairs of unconnected nodes, i.e. if

```
connected = (sum(C(:)) == N ^ 2)
```

---

I'm not sure how one would define connectedness in a **two-mode network**. A simple approach would be to just disregard the difference between the two types of nodes, and consider them all to be part of a one-mode network. If `M` is the original two-mode network matrix of size `[m, n] = size(M)`, then

```
M = [zeros(m, m) , M ; M' ; zeros(n, n)];
```

converts it into the matrix describing the corresponding one-mode network of size `(m+n)`x`(m+n)`.

---

These matrix powers do not only tell you whether the whole network is connected, they can also be used to find the connected sub-networks (network clusters) if it is not. Since the behavior of powers of a matrix is closely connected to its spectral decomposition (a.k.a. [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix)), this idea leads to the approach of [spectral clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering). For an application to weighted synchronization networks, see e.g. [arXiv:0706.3375](http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2479).